# Why does for loop not execute?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am having trouble figuring out while my `for` loop never executes. Tje code is below:

```
char word[10];

word[0] = 'a';
word[1] = 'b';
word[2] = 'c';
word[3] = '\0';

char* ptr = word;
int x = 0;
int counter = 0;

for ( char c = *(ptr + x); c == '\0'; c = *(ptr + x))
{
   counter++;
   x++;
}
```

After execution of this loop counter is equal to 0, because the loop was never entered.

Comment: Think of the conditional expression in the `for` loop as you would for a `while` loop. It's not a terminating condition.

Comment: I suggest you edit your original post (OP) and let people know what you have already tried to do to solve this problem. For example, did you use a debugger? If so, what did you find?

Comment: In C, `for` loops don't run **until** a condition is true, they run **while** it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is backwards.  You want to test `c != '\0'`.